# Conditionally load JS based on whether or not a field has data?

Tags: theming, javascript

I'd like to load a javascript file only if a specific field has data. Can this be done with a preprocess function in template.php? Something like:

```
if this field is not empty
  add the js to the page footer
else do nothing
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a field within a specific content type has some content, load some javascript, if there's nothing in the field, do nothing.

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == "CONTENT_TYPE") {
    if(!empty($variables['node']->FIELD_NAME)) {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') . 'PATH-TO-JS.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer'));

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: something wrong happened I guess,please add your snippet again

Answer (score 1):

yes, doable at your template.php file

not the exact code but should be pretty close.

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == "your_content_type") {
     dpm($variables['node']); // to check debugg inside your node(devel module needed)
     if($variables['node']->yourfieldname != "") {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A slight variation of this worked

Comment: if the variation is not specific, please share would be help for others searching for something same :)

Comment: New to this site, answered my own question with the variation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please add the snippet one more time, something wrong happened while editing :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that it's a node page, you can do it in your template.php as follows:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $content = $variables['content'];
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    if ($content['YOUR_FIELD']) {
      $js_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME') . '/yourjs.js';
      drupal_add_js($js_path, array('scope' => 'footer'));
    }
  }
}
```